# Mid-view UITabBarController IOS 7

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to build an iPhone app (ios 7+) that has a view very similar to the one in the attached image.  If I had to guess, it looks like a UITabBar in the middle, with a customized UITableView inside each page, and an ImageView up top, all wrapped in a NavigationView?  Is it possible to build this app's screen using these components, or is it a whole bunch of fancy custom stuff going on behind the scenes?

Specifically, I care about the tab bar in the middle of the view, controlling what is seen below it.  Might that be a UITabBarController?

[image: attached image]

Comment: It looks like a skinned UIToolBar with custom view switching. Or perhaps a custom UIControl altogether.

Comment: Hmm, alright, I think I can make something similar with the UIToolBar...  I was really hoping I could jam a UITabBarController in there, move it to the middle, tell it to show the pages below, and call it a day...  But I guess not.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While UITabBar and UISegmentedControl are fairly similar, they are both best suited for different tasks - In this case, a UISegmentedControl is best.

It can be visually customized quite well, seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW33) in Apple's documentation.

Because it's a UIControl subclass unlike UITabBar, you can add targets for control events really easily, like this:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UITabBar` and conform to the `UITabBarDelegate` to receive tab bar changes such as a different tab chosen, then change your views appropriately. A *`UITabBarController`* is a controller for managing a tab based view controller hierarchy which is not what you want because it would result in multiple view controllers on screen at a time, which is very frowned upon by apple.

Comment: So I can pop a UITabBar into the middle of a View, put a Container View below it, and on different tab choice, swap Views in and out of the Container View?  Is that better than using a UIToolBar?  It sounds to me like it would be the same?

Comment: Yes. That should be ok.

Comment: Great, so I can create 3 views with tables ahead-of-time and pop 'em in and out as need be?  They won't go away or get reset if I switch back and forth and back again?  Also, multiple view controllers at once is bad, but having these few views living in memory at once is okay, right?

Comment: I would try to populate a single table view and reload the data depending on the tab.

Comment: But what if each item needs to keep some sort of state?  Back to the example picture, if each menu item needs to know if it's been ordered already, you'd need to be able to go back to that menu and un-select it.  I mean, that wouldn't be bad to rebuild the table and mark the ordered ones appropriately - I just thought it'd be easier to keep the entire already-up-to-date view in memory and swap it back in.

Comment: @jcovert you could but make sure to watch your memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59904/discussion-between-milo-and-jcovert).